# Calculating the Franck-Condon Factors

Tags: molecules, quantum-chemistry

I want to calculate the Frank-Condon Factors using the standard equation:
$$q_{v'v''}=\left[\int \psi_{v'}^* \psi_{v''}  dr\right]^2$$

I have the vibrational wave functions of $v'$ and $v''$ in numeric form (i.e. points and not in analytical form). Now, if we take the complex conjugate of the vibrational wave function $v'$ and we multiply it with the vibrational wave function $v''$, we get a single value as an integrand.

My question is, how can we solve the integral in this case:

1. Is it a definite integral? If yes, then what are the lower and upper boundaries in this case? Are they the internuclear distances $r'_e$ and $r''_e$?
2. If not, and it is an indefinite integral, then we will get a single value multiplied by a variable, and thus not obtaining a value of the FCF which is between 0 and 1.